# SQL selecting row multiple times depending on clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with an "id", "alarm" and "deadline". "alarm" and "deadline" are two date-time strings. To show the entries in an agenda I would like to select every row with an alarm and every row with a deadline in a single field, so a row can be selected multiple times. At the end I would like to order by "alarm" and "deadline" so that in the end everything is correctly sorted by the dates. My date format is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". Does anyone have an idea how to write the query?

For example I have the following dataset:

```
id: "1", alarm: "15-12-2020 13:45:00", deadline: ""

id: "2", alarm: "16-12-2020 14:35:00", deadline: "18-12-2020 18:00:00"

id: "3", alarm: "", deadline: ""

id: "4", alarm: "", deadline: "17-12-2020 16:35:00"
```

"alarm" and "deadline" as "date". The Output should be:

```
id: "1", date: "15-12-2020 13:45:00"

id: "2", date: "16-12-2020 14:35:00"

id: "4", date: "17-12-2020 16:35:00"

id: "2", date: "18-12-2020 18:00:00"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to unpivot and sort?

```
select t.*
from (select alarm as dt, 'alarm' as which from t union all
      select deadline, 'deadline' as which from t
     ) t
order by dt
```